# getting error on passing values in GetAsync method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i have already defined API which display the full information of student when email and password is provided . But when i want to use that API from another project its not able to pass the values of email and password.

```
    [Route("CallApiGet")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CallAPIGET()
    {
          using (var client = new HttpClient())
          {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44376/");
            var GetData = new
              {
                 Email = "abc@gmail.com",
                 Password = "dhdsi@hc"
              };

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/CustomerController",content))
             {
                var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return Ok(responseContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: code]

I have tried passing the value of email and password in variable content but getting error.

Answer (score 0):

A httpget has no body ( content ) so if you use a get then you should use query parameters.

The get URL should be more like:

```
ApiUrl/controller?email=xxxx&password=yyyy
```

Your endpoint presumably has these as parameters.

Having said that, a httpget is no secure. It's just a plain string with a password in it.

I suggest you consider changing this endpoint to a post and then you can send parameters in the body. Assuming this is Https they will then be encrypted and rather more secure.

Comment: HTTPS encrypts the requested URL; it is only the domain name that is (usually) unencrypted, and that's only because of DNS, not HTTPS.

Comment: You still have passwords in your browser history @stephen cleary